# In my TCP Connection, Client sends Hello but Server receives Hellob

Tags: c, tcp, client-server

as you can see in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoG9q.png)

if a client writes `Ciao`, server receives `Ciaob`; but sometimes it correctly receives `Ciao`.

This is my *client.c* file:

```
int main ()
{
    int clientSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    char buffer[1024];
    int connectionStatus;
    ssize_t nread;

// Creazione della socket
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (clientSocket == -1) {
    perror("[-]Errore durante la creazione della socket\n");
    exit(-1);
}


memset(&serverAddress, '\0', sizeof(serverAddress));

// Riempimento dei campi della struct
serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddress.sin_port = htons(PORT);
serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

// Connessione
connectionStatus = connect(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
if (connectionStatus == -1) {
    perror("Errore con la connessione\n");
    exit(-1);
}

while (1) {

    printf("> ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", buffer);

    // Invio dei dati
    if (send(clientSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0) <= 0) {
        perror("Errore con l'invio");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Riceve i dati dalla socket
    if ( (nread=recv(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof buffer -1, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("[-]Error in receiving data\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("nread is %ld\n", nread);
        buffer[nread] = '\0';
        printf("Server received: %s\n", buffer);
    }

}

close(clientSocket);

return 0;
}
```

and this is my *server.c*

```
#define PORT 4444
#define MAX_CONNESSIONI 100

int main ()
{
    int serverSocket, bindStatus;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress;
    int clientSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in newAddress;
    char buffer[1024];
    pid_t child;
    socklen_t addrSize;

    // Creazione della socket
    serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (serverSocket == -1) {
        perror("[-]Errore durante la creazione della socket\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("[+]Echo-Server socket has been created\n");

    memset(&serverAddress, '\0', sizeof(serverAddress));

    // Riempimento dei campi della struct
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    // Binding della socket all'indirizzo specificato. Associa alla socket un indirizzo in modo da poter essere contattata dai client
    bindStatus = bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress));
    if (bindStatus == -1) {
        perror("[-]Errore durante il binding\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    // Imposta la socket all'ascolto. I parametri sono il descrittore della socket e la massima lunghezza della coda di connessioni entranti
    if (listen(serverSocket, MAX_CONNESSIONI) != -1) {
        printf("Listening . . .\n\n");
    }
    else {
        perror("[-]Error during listening\n");
        exit(1);
    }


    while (1) {

        // Accettazione della connessione
        clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&newAddress, &addrSize);
        if (clientSocket == -1) {
            exit(-1);
        }
        printf("%s:%d joined\n", inet_ntoa(newAddress.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddress.sin_port));

        child = fork();
        if (child == 0) {

            close(serverSocket);

            while (1) {

                // Ricezione del messaggio
                recv(clientSocket, buffer, 1024, 0);

                if (strcmp(buffer, ":exit") == 0) {
                    printf("%s:%d left\n", inet_ntoa(newAddress.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddress.sin_port));
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    printf("%s:%d wrote: %s\n", inet_ntoa(newAddress.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddress.sin_port), buffer);
                    // Invio del messaggio
                    send(clientSocket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
                    bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                }

            }

        }

    }

    close(clientSocket);

    return 0;
}
```

- Where's the mistake?

Probably the mistake is in this file when I use `scanf` function, but I can't figure out why it does not work properly. Or replace it using a `read` system call

Note this:

[Ciao but nread id 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL2Z4.png)

Comment: My guess? You forgot the string null terminator. You need to keep track of the value returned by `recv` so you know where to add it to the string you receive.

Comment: The `printf` `%s` format specifier needs a null-terminated string.

Comment: You send `strlen(buffer)` bytes. That doesn't include the NUL terminator so you are not sending a valid C string. Either you need to send one extra byte or the receiver needs to add in the NUL terminator.

Comment: Also, it's unlikely to hit you in such a simple example but TCP is a streaming protocol and there is no guarantee on how much data each `recv` call will actually receive. Hence the return value of `recv` needs to be checked to get the number of received bytes. That is, each `recv` call in your example may receive less than the full string that was sent.

Comment: I edited the post but the problem persists

Answer (score 1):

The data you send and receive don't include the string zero terminator, you need to add that manually:

E.g.:

```
ssize_t len = recv(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof buffer - 1, 0); // -1 for the zero terminator.
if(len <= 0)
    // process error.
buffer[len] = 0; // Zero-terminate received data.
printf("Server received: %s\n", buffer);
```

`send` and `recv` may send/receive less data than you requested. The code needs to handle that by examining the return code and invoking `send`/`recv` in a loop.

---

I test your code by running an echo server server with `socat`:

```
$ socat -v tcp-l:2222,fork exec:'/bin/cat'
> 2020/02/13 11:36:42.099857  length=3 from=0 to=2
abc< 2020/02/13 11:36:42.099974  length=3 from=0 to=2
abc> 2020/02/13 11:36:48.589751  length=3 from=3 to=5
def< 2020/02/13 11:36:48.589843  length=3 from=3 to=5
```

Client:

```
$ ./debug/gcc/test 
> abc
Server received: abc
> def
Server received: def
>   C-c C-c
```

Comment: I replaced my `scanf` statement with a `buffer[read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, 1000)] = '\0';`. It seems to work properly. Is that correct?

Comment: @ItsGhost To make your solutions correct you need to handle errors.

Comment: I added an if clause as follows: `nread = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, 1000);
        if (nread != -1)
            buffer[nread] = '\0';`

Comment: @ItsGhost That's better. But then you have to remember to make your `buffer` an array of at least `1001` characters. I also suggest you use `sizeof` rather than hard-code the length. As in `sizeof buffer - 1` (where `-1` is for the space for the terminator).

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin your solution does not work properly (same problems as per my solution with scanf)..

Comment: I edited my code and as you can see, even though I put your solution, I get the same problem

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin as you can see, the problem persists even though I added your solution

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I added my server.c code and another screenshot problem

Comment: @ItsGhost The code works as expected for me. Added output, so that you can see.

Comment: @ItsGhost `recv` code in your server suffers from the same problem, and it needs the same fix.

Comment: Thank you, seems to be.

Comment: @ItsGhost You should get used to handling *all* return values and errors, that will eliminate the entire class of bugs in your code.